# js array filter based on two boolean conditions

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two boolean conditions to filter an array. An array will always have 3 items within, and first condition always removes 2nd item, second condition 3rd one. And I successfully filtering it using `.filter`. But seems my approach a bit dirty, is there any better, clear way to filter?

```js
  const firstCondition = true;
  const secondCondition = true;

  const arrayToFilter: Array<string> = ['firstItem', 'secondItem', 'thirdItem'].filter(
    (item, idx) =>
      firstCondition && secondCondition 
        ? item
        : !firstCondition && secondCondition 
        ? idx !== 1
        : !firstCondition && !secondCondition 
        ? idx === 0
        : firstCondition && !secondCondition && idx !== 2
  );

console.log(arrayToFilter);
```

**Edit: Clarification**
If Conditions are false they removes items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
 const arrayToFilter: Array<string> = ['firstItem', 'secondItem', 'thirdItem'].filter(
(item, idx) => {
    if (!firstCondition && idx === 1) return false
    if (!secondCondition && idx === 2) return false
    else return true 
  }
);
```

Comment: Nice, but I've changed logic a bit to fulfill my expectations, to !firstCondition, !secondCondition. Definitely better than what I wrote.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. I have updated my answer to fit your edited description.

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
....
(item, index) => (
  (firstCondition && index !== 1)
  || (secondCondition && index !== 2)
  || true // (!firstCondition && !secondCondition)
)
```

Comment: Your approach is looking pretty, but seems your first two conditions within brackets() has to return false to properly filtering but they returning true, or I am missing something? I've tried to use it but it gives me wrong result. Like if 1-true,  2-true I see an empty array.

Comment: yeah, index values were wrong 2 & 3, instead of 1 & 2

Comment: No, I've changed them to 1&2 before checking)